# If $f$ is and endomorphism in $E$ (euclidian vectorial space)...

Tags: linear-algebra

We have that for every $(x,y) \in E$ holds

$$(f(x),y)=(x,f(y))$$

How do I show that $\operatorname{Im}(f)$ is ortoghonal to $\ker(f)$?

Thank you very much, it's been a while I've been trying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$x \in \ker f \iff f(x) = 0\iff \langle f(x), y\rangle = 0, \forall y \in E \iff \langle x, f(y)\rangle = 0, \forall y \in E \iff x \perp \operatorname{Im} f$$

so $\ker f = (\operatorname{Im} f)^\perp$. In particular $\ker f \perp \operatorname{Im} f$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x\in\operatorname{ker} f$ and let $z\in\operatorname{im} f$.  Then $f(x)=0$ and $z=f(y)$ for some $y\in E$.  Now $(x,z)=(x,f(y))=(f(x),y)=(0,y)=0$.

Comment: Okay, I don't think that (f(x),y) is the notation for the scalar product in this case, because we used in the whole book (a|b)

Comment: but I was a little bit confused because of the notation, thank you very much =)

Comment: Yeah I found the notation confusing because you also wrote $(x,y)$ in $E$.  I assumed it meant the inner product though;  and that you just meant $x,y\in E$.  You're certainly welcome.